# Валидация json данных в python

Tags: python, json, валидация, try-catch

Я новичок в Python, не судите строго... Кажется, это действительно тривиальный вопрос.

Мне нужно создать функцию, которая проверяет входящие данные JSON и возвращает Python dict. Я хочу быть уверен, что необходимые мне поля присутствуют в JSON файле и они заполнены корректно, а также проверить типы данных этих полей. Мне нужно использовать try-catch.

Не могли бы вы поделиться какими-то сниппетами или примерами, которые дадут мне ответы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужна библиотека `jsonschema`, данная библиотека позволяет проводить верификацию json по заданной схеме. И если обнаружены ошибки будет выдавать их в виде исключений с описанием. В схеме можно указывать как тип полей, так и диапазон допустимых значений, значения по умолчанию и пр.

```
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
            },
        "age": {"type": "number",
                "minimum": 18,
                "maximum": 110
                },
        "role": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["admin", "user"]
            }
        }
    }

message = {"name": "Vasya", "age": 15, "role": "user"}

validate(message, schema)
```

Более подробно про создание схем можно посмотреть в стандарте [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/)

Comment: Очень оказалось полезно в моем случае, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь модулем `json`. Метод [`loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) принимает JSON-строку и возвращает словарь Python. Если JSON не валидный, то будет вызвано исключение [`JSONDecodeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError).

```
>>> import json
>>> json_string = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
>>> d = json.loads(json_string)
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d['b']
2
```

Дальше можете работать со словарем (делать проверки и т.п.).

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

1. Определяете схему данных при помощи датакласса ValidatedDC

```py
    from dataclasses import dataclass
    from typing import List, Union

    from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


    @dataclass
    class Foo(ValidatedDC):
        value: Union[int, List[int]]


    @dataclass
    class Bar(ValidatedDC):
        foo: Union[Foo, List[Foo]]
```

2. Получаете  json строку и загружаете ее в словарь или в список словарей при помощи json.loads()
3. Примеры валидации:

```py
    # --- Valid input ---

    foo = {'value': 1}
    instance = Bar(foo=foo)
    assert instance.get_errors() is None
    assert instance == Bar(foo=Foo(value=1))

    foo = {'value': [1, 2]}
    instance = Bar(foo=foo)
    assert instance.get_errors() is None
    assert instance == Bar(foo=Foo(value=[1, 2]))

    foo = [{'value': 1}, {'value': 2}]
    instance = Bar(foo=foo)
    assert instance.get_errors() is None
    assert instance == Bar(foo=[Foo(value=1), Foo(value=2)])

    foo = [{'value': [1, 2]}, {'value': [3, 4]}]
    instance = Bar(foo=foo)
    assert instance.get_errors() is None
    assert instance == Bar(foo=[Foo(value=[1, 2]), Foo(value=[3, 4])])


    # --- Invalid input ---

    foo = {'value': 'S'}
    instance = Bar(foo=foo)
    assert instance.get_errors()
    assert instance == Bar(foo={'value': 'S'})
    # fix
    instance.foo['value'] = 1
    assert instance.is_valid()
    assert instance.get_errors() is None
    assert instance == Bar(foo=Foo(value=1))

    foo = [{'value': [1, 2]}, {'value': ['S', 4]}]
    instance = Bar(foo=foo)
    assert instance.get_errors()
    assert instance == Bar(foo=[{'value': [1, 2]}, {'value': ['S', 4]}])
    # fix
    instance.foo[1]['value'][0] = 3
    assert instance.is_valid()
    assert instance.get_errors() is None
    assert instance == Bar(foo=[Foo(value=[1, 2]), Foo(value=[3, 4])])


    # --- get_errors() ---

    foo = {'value': 'S'}
    instance = Bar(foo=foo)
    print(instance.get_errors())
    # {
    #   'foo': [
    #       # An unsuccessful attempt to use the dictionary to create a Foo instance
    #       InstanceValidationError(
    #           value_repr="{'value': 'S'}",
    #           value_type=<class 'dict'>,
    #           annotation=<class '__main__.Foo'>,
    #           exception=None,
    #           errors={
    #               'value': [
    #                   BasicValidationError(  # because the str isn't an int
    #                       value_repr='S', value_type=<class 'str'>,
    #                       annotation=<class 'int'>, exception=None
    #                   ),
    #                   BasicValidationError(  # and the str is not a list of int
    #                       value_repr='S', value_type=<class 'str'>,
    #                       annotation=typing.List[int], exception=None
    #                   )
    #               ]
    #           }
    #       ),
    #       BasicValidationError(  # the dict is not a list of Foo
    #           value_repr="{'value': 'S'}",
    #           value_type=<class 'dict'>,
    #           annotation=typing.List[__main__.Foo],
    #           exception=None
    #       )
    #   ]
    # }
```

Ссылка на ValidatedDC: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc